# Proof that pointwise convergence can disrupt convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, pointwise-convergence

I'm trying to get a grasp on point-wise convergence and am hoping to prove something to give a concrete example of why it's weak. The lemma goes as follows .

Suppose $f _ { n } : [ a , b ] \rightarrow \mathbb { R }$ is a sequence of continuous functions
 that converge point wise , but  **NOT UNIFORMLY** to a continuous function $ f : [ a , b ] \rightarrow \mathbb { R } $ .

Then there exists a convergence sequence $ x _ { n } \rightarrow x \operatorname { in } [ a , b ] $ such that $f _ { n } \left( x _ { n } \right)$ does not converge to $ f(x) $ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the convergence is not uniform there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $f_{n_i}(x_{n_i})$ (where we can assume the $x_{n_i}$ are convergent to some $x$ because $[a,b]$ is compact) such that $|f_{n_i}(x_{n_i})-f(x_{n_i})|\ge \epsilon$. For $i$ large enough, $|f(x)-f(x_{n_i})|<\epsilon/2$. By the Reverse Triangle Inequality:
$$ |f_{n_i}(x_{n_i})-f(x)|\ge||f_{n_i}(x_{n_i})-f(x_{n_i})| -|f(x_{n_i})-f(x)||\ge \epsilon/2$$
So $f_{n_i}(x_{n_i})$ cannot converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is 99% of it! Do you mind clarifying the initial claim. From lacking uniform convergence, we're finding a small enough $ \epsilon $ so that the norm is not always less than it for all the elements in the sequence? That doesn't seem trivial to me. I'm also confused why you seemed to take two norms in your final inequality. Finally a proposed an edit about redefining $ 2 \epsilon $ so your final inequality is more obviously sufficient?

Comment: $f_n\to f$ uniformly iff $\lim \max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$. If we do not have uniform convergence, this limit does not exist so there must be some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for any $N$, there is some $n\ge N$ with $\max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$, so you can find an $x_n$ with $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\ge\epsilon$. You can then repeat this process to obtain the subsequence in the initial claim.